# Pandas read_csv suddenly reads in int as object and I can't change it

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

I am working with pandas to read in a .dat file using the command

`'recoil = pd.read_csv('partic_tran_r.dat', engine='python', skiprows=9, sep='\s+')`

When I ask for the data types with `'recoil.dtypes'` I get back the following:

```
pid              object
projectile       object
species          object
gen              object
collision        object
medium          float64
huge            float64
fluence         float64
...
...
dtype: object
```

So most of the data types are identified correctly but seemingly suddenly the first five ones aren't.
When I try to modify `dtype=int` as a parameter in the `read_csv()` then I only get the error message `ValueError: Unable to convert column pid to type <class 'int'>`.

I didn't have this issue before and I'm unaware of what is different now compared to before.
My use case for having this as int or float is that I want to create a unique id:

```
projectile['unique_id'] = projectile['pid'] + projectile['projectile'] * 10
```

and it was returning for `pid=3` and `patricle=74`: `unique_id=374(74 repeated 10 times)`, although I didn't have this issue before and the code worked without problems.

Thank you for any suggestions as how to fix this or circumvent it.
P.S. I'm writing my code in the newest version of JupyterLab in Anaconda on Windows10 all updated with `conda update --all`

Comment: share the csv so we can see what can go wrong with the `pid`

Comment: Yes, that is a good point. I already found the error thanks to the answer from @Corralien which is that there was a footer in this .dat file, which I didn't know was there and I forgot to look in the most obvious place and only looked at the ´projectile.head()´

Comment: Have you tried changing it after you read it in. Maybe something like this `recoil['pid'] = recoil.pid.astype('int32')`

Comment: Hey @j__carlson, yes I have but that has not worked, unfortunately Corralien deleted his answer where I responded.

The answer was that in a new .dat file version there was a footer which only affected the first columns, as there was text at the bottom. Removing those or accounting for them by setting the footer parameter in 'read_csv' worked. So it was my issue of being too focused on the 'x.head()' instead of the whole dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so just out of completeness I wanted to post the answer as an answer and not only in the comments:

I didn't look closely enough at the .dat file which had two strings at the end that were new in the .dat compared to an older version.
So simply accounting for it in the `footer` parameter of `pd.read_csv()` or deleting them naturally solved the issue of casting the whole column as objects not int64.